# Azure B2C custom policy and Client Id

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, policy

I'm trying to set up a custom Azure B2C policy. When I'm setting up my TrustedFrameworkExtensions.xml file I'm stumbling at ClaimsProvider and some fields.

The question is the following: Where do I get the value for "client_id" and "IdTokenAudience"?

Thanks in advance

```
 <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
         <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 6):

If my understanding is correct, based on [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-kmsi-custom) those are application ids, of two application with given name in your B2C. In the doc above there is an other link [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) which describes what application you should define:

- IdentityExperienceFramework (with this exact name)
- ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework (with this exact name)

After those two exist, you can use their application Id in your policy XML in place of ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId and IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId respectively

Answer (score 3):

To obtain both values you need to Register 2 applications as described in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom).

1. Go to your Azure AD B2C directory.
2. Open Azure Active Directory from the menu and create both applications as described in the docs.
3. Enter both ID values of the applications to the TrustedFrameworkExtensions.xml file under appropriate fields. The docs says both values. So you end up with the XML similar to this:

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">7b48c557-...</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">b7adf4e5-...</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="7b48c557..." />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="b7adf4e5-..." />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```